# Python функция, которая будет спрашивать возраст у человека, и вычтить возраст человека на среднестатистическую продолжительность человека

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python Нужно написать функцию, которая будет спрашивать возраст у человека, и вычтить возраст человека на среднестатистическую продолжительность человека Чтобы вывело в консоль сколько ему осталось до смерти. Прошу помочь всем неравнодушным
Очень короткую программу, в пару строк кода

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: _Очень короткую программу, в пару строк кода_ - так почему бы самому не написать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй разобраться сам, что есть что:

```
def how_long_to_live(age_of_life):
    """Получает на вход среднюю продолжительность жизни."""
    age = int(input('Сколько Вам лет?\n'))
    if age < age_of_life:
        print('В среднем, вам осталось прожить {} лет\n'.format(age_of_life-age))
    elif age == age_of_life:
        print('Вполне возможно, это ваш последний год жизни.\n')
    else:
        print('Вы уже прожили на {} лет больше среднего.\n').format(age-age_of_life)


how_long_to_live(72)
```